# MYSQL query from multiple tables with multiple counts and a calculated row

Tags: mysql, count, union

Desperately need some help, I have three tables.  A cards table for employee names, an enquiry table for generated leads, and a job table for, well, jobs.

I'm trying to do a query that involves returning the count of leads and the count of jobs for each employee and calculate the conversion ratio for each employee.

Cards table schema is like this:-

```
cards
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| PK_CardID |  LastName  |   FirstName |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|         1 | Andrews    | John        |
|         2 | Smith      | Cynthia     |
|         3 | Jones      | Adam        |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

enquiries table schema is like this:-

```
+--------------+-----------+------------+
| PK_EnquiryID | FK_CardID | DateAdded  |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
|            1 |         1 | 1995-01-21 |
|            2 |         3 | 1995-01-22 |
|            3 |         1 | 1995-01-23 |
|            4 |         2 | 1995-01-21 |
+--------------+-----------+------------+
```

jobs table schema is like this:-

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| PK_JobID | FK_CardID | DateAdded  |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|        1 |         3 | 1995-01-25 |
|        2 |         2 | 1995-01-26 |
|        3 |         3 | 1995-01-24 |
|        4 |         1 | 1995-01-26 |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

so i want to return something like the following

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+
| PK_CardID |  LastName  |   FirstName | countEnquiries | countJobs | ConversionRatio |
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+
|         1 | Andrews    | John        |              2 |         1 | 50%             |
|         2 | Smith      | Cynthia     |              1 |         1 | 100%            |
|         3 | Jones      | Adam        |              1 |         2 | 200%            |
+-----------+------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

So far my SQL looks like this

```
SELECT PK_CardID, LastName, FirstName
                (SELECT count(PK_EnquiryID) FROM enquiries WHERE PK_Cardid = FK_CardID) as countEnq,
                (SELECT count(PK_JobID) FROM jobs WHERE PK_CardID = FK_CardID) as countJob
                FROM enquiries";
```

However this is clearly very incorrect, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways this can be handled, and subselects as you attempted is one of them, but it tends to be quite slow. Since the `COUNT()` aggregates have to be applied separately on the `jobs` and `enquiries` tables, you may join against two subqueries which return the counts per `PK_CardID`.

```
SELECT
  c.PK_CardID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  enquiries,
  jobs,
  jobs/enquiries * 100 AS conversionratio
FROM
  cards c
  /* Separately retrieve the count of enquiries and count of jobs
     LEFT JOINs are used in case there are none returned from either 
     related table */
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT FK_CardID, COUNT(*) AS enquiries
     FROM enquiries
     GROUP BY FK_CardID
  ) e ON c.PK_CardID = e.FK_CardID
  LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT FK_CardID, COUNT(*) AS jobs
     FROM jobs
     GROUP BY FK_CardID
  ) j ON c.PK_CardID = j.FK_CardID
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/915940/1

To complete it using subselects as you attempted, you need to relate the subselect to the main table (`cards`) in its `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  c.PK_CardID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) AS enquiries,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) AS jobs,
  /* Unless the whole thing is wrapped in a subquery, you need to *recalculate* these subselects
     to use them in the calculated field, which is very slow. The method above 
     is more efficient. */
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) * 100 as conversionratio
FROM
  cards c
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/915940/2

...Avoid recalculating by wrapping the whole thing:

```
SELECT
  PK_CardID,
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  enquiries,
  jobs,
  /* calculation performed in the outer query with values from the inner's subselects */
  jobs / enquiries * 100 AS conversionratio
FROM (
  SELECT
    c.PK_CardID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) AS enquiries,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobs WHERE FK_CardID = c.PK_CardID) AS jobs
  FROM cards c
```

) AS wrapper

Answer (score 1):

The query that you are trying to write looks like this:

```
SELECT c.PK_CardID, c.LastName, c.FirstName
       (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries e WHERE c.PK_Cardid = e.FK_CardID) as countEnq,
       (SELECT count(*) FROM jobs j WHERE c.PK_CardID = j.FK_CardID) as countJob
FROM cards c;
```

The major difference from your query is the `cards` in the outer `from` clause.  To get the ratio, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT PK_CardID, LastName, FirstName, countEnq, countJob,
       100*(countEnq / countJob) as ConversionRatio
FROM (SELECT c.PK_CardID, c.LastName, c.FirstName
             (SELECT count(*) FROM enquiries e WHERE c.PK_Cardid = e.FK_CardID) as countEnq,
             (SELECT count(*) FROM jobs j WHERE c.PK_CardID = j.FK_CardID) as countJob
      FROM cards c
     ) c;
```